# How many characters in Dragon Ball can fire Kienzan-like discs?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

So far I remember 6 characters in Dragon Ball firing Kienzan-like discs. Who are all the characters who can fire them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Dragon Ball Wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Destructo_Disc), these characters have used this or similar technique:

- Krillin
- Vegeta
- Frieza
- Amond (Dragon Ball Z: The Tree of Might)
- Goku
- Cell
- Cell Juniors
- Android 18
- Baby Vegeta (Dragon Ball GT)
- Super Buu (The result of Evil Buu eating Good Buu in a chocolate form)
- Master Roshi (Dragon Ball Z: Atsumare! Gokū Wārudo)
- Future Warrior (Dragon Ball Xenoverse Game)

Comment: Master Roshi? I never remember him firing it

Comment: well the media is extended and as you see the characters are not excursive to the anime. I see if I can find where he uses it